# FFmpeg creates a small audible dropout_transition pre and post audio overlay, how do I remove this?

Tags: ffmpeg

file1.wav is 25 minutes long. file2.wav is 20 seconds long. File2.wav delays to the end of the file1.wav and the two are "amixed" together. The delay works perfect and overlays into the correct location at the end of the 25 minute file1.wav file. My problem is the blending of the two clips together -- I believe the dropout_transition (even though it's set to 0) still creates an audible undesireable "dip" before and after file2.wav overlays onto file1.wav. Is there a way to ensure that no "dips" happen at all? The two clips are well-balanced with either using mixing software so I don't want them change at all, but I also don't want distortion. Is this possible? Is it possible to use amerge instead of amix as an alternative? I tried but I can't figure out the correct syntax. Help from geniuses appreciated!

I've tried various different dropout_transition settings and volume settings...this is as close as I've come to desired results. Like I said, I can't figure out the correct syntax to use amerge instead of amix.

```
ffmpeg -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -filter_complex "[1]adelay=70751488S|#70751488S,volume=1[b];[0][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,volume=2" /output.wav
```

Comment: At the moment the `amix`-filter, for reasons unknown to me, always does "volume normalization" and can't be turned off. I reported it [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8033) a couple of days ago. No reaction since. In the meantime you could set the `dropout_transition` to the length of the entire output and crank up the volume after that. I've explained this in the ticket as well. The `amerge`-filter btw merges **channels**, which I believe is not what you want.

Comment: @Reino, skipping normalization risks clipping and flattening out the output.

Comment: It's strange that you get a dip "before" overlay since what adelay does is add silent frames in front. So the mixing has started at t=0.

Comment: @Gyan, not when your audio segments are intended to be mixed at full volume.

Comment: Since my duration is 25 minutes I'll set the dropout_transition to 1,500 seconds and see how that works. @Gyan - I believe to prevent distortion you use the "alimiter" command although I haven't implemented it yet. Not sure if this code works: ffmpeg -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -filter_complex "[1]adelay=70751488S|#70751488S,volume=1[b];[0][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=1500,volume=2[m];[m]alimiter[a]" -map [a] /output.wav

Comment: @Gyan, when I mix these I render in dips into the long audio file for the placement of 20 second clip. So I want both clips at 100% volume--it's okay if they are both decreased equally in volume across the entire length of the file to prevent clipping as long as intrinsic mix between them remains intact.

Comment: What's up with the `#` in `adelay`'s parameters? Typo? `volume=1` does nothing here. Have you done a `volumedetect` to know `volume=2` is the right value to raise the volume to where it was before? Btw, please use formatting for your code.

Answer (score 0):

It works! Here's the solution. 1) As stated, make sure that your dropout transition = length of longest file in seconds. Thank you for this 2) The two files I was using were 48/16bit wave files. Make sure that you export 32-bit floating point wave files to be mixed together. From the manual: **amix** only supports "floating point samples; If the amix input has integer samples then **aresample** will be automatically inserted to perform the conversion to float samples." Apparently, this works but aresample somehow messes up the transitions when you don't use 32-bit wave files. No idea why just avoid this conversion and only use 32-bit wave files. 3) Note: When combining two .wav files together the total lowered output is -6dB. This is to prevent distortion and is normal. So the question is why did aresample mess things up for me?