# FFmpeg amix-filter always does "volume normalization". How to prevent it and what are the possible drawbacks of it?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

There are many questions on this topic [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509147/ffmpeg-amix-filter-volume-issue-with-inputs-of-different-duration/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712868/ffmpeg-set-volume-in-amix), and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856602/ffmpeg-amix-filter-volume-changes-explanation-request). However, I am asking for suggestions on the probable solution and if it has some drawbacks.

**Problem Definition:** amix-filter always does "volume normalization" and can't be turned off

Reference: Please read comments over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238208/ffmpeg-creates-a-small-audible-dropout-transition-pre-and-post-audio-overlay-ho) by @[Reino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703456/reino). He also had opened a [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8033) on the FFmpeg forum to explain the situation.

**Hacky Solution:** amix=inputs=13:dropout_transition=1000,volume=13

Reference: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712495/3598052), and also in the [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8033).

**Questions:**

**1)** "amix scales each input's volume by 1/n where n = no. of active inputs. This is evaluated for each audio frame. So when an input drops out, the volume of the remaining inputs is scaled by a smaller amount, hence their volumes increase."[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714779/3598052)

For example, if I am merging 10 audio streams then, the 1st audio stream will be scaled by 1/10, 2nd by 1/9, 3rd by 1/8 .. 9th by 1/2 and last 10th by 1. Have I understood this correctly or let me know if I am missing something?

**2) [dropout_transition](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix):** The transition time, in seconds, for volume renormalization when an input stream ends. The default value is 2 seconds.

dropout_transition means **it will SKIP given seconds**, right? So if I set dropout_transition=1000(very large number) then regardless of video length FFmpeg will drop/skip audio transition for provided seconds. Again, please do correct me if I have made wrong assumption.

**3)** I have tried many other solutions without any luck and now I am relying profoundly on the provided solution. Is there any drawback to the above hacky solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*if I am merging 10 audio streams then, the 1st audio stream will be scaled by 1/10, 2nd by 1/9, 3rd by 1/8 .. 9th by 1/2 and last 10th by 1.*

No. Let's say you have 4 inputs, which are 10, 7, 4 and 2 seconds long respectively. Let's keep dropout transition as 0. Then for first 2 seconds, all inputs are active, so each input is scaled by 1/4. From 2 to 4 seconds, 3 inputs are active, so all active  inputs (#1, 2, 3) are scaled by 1/3. From 4 to 7 seconds, only inputs 1 and 2 are active, so both are scaled by 1/2. And from 7 to 10 seconds, only input 1 is active, so it is scaled by 1 i.e. its volume is unchanged.

*dropout_transition means it will SKIP given seconds, right?*

No. Continuing with the above scenario, let's say dropout transition is 1 second. So, when input 4 ends, the scaling does not change from 1/4 to 1/3 immediately. It transitions over 1 second, gradually.

*Is there any drawback to the above hacky solution?*

For most cases, it's fine. If you're combining loud pieces of music, then there will be flattening of range, but it shouldn't matter in that case.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts and approving the solution.