# Normalizing audio in ffmpeg - how?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm creating one of those "Brady Bunch" videos for a choir using a C# application I'm writing that uses ffmpeg for all the heavy lifting, and for the most part it's working great but I'm having trouble getting the audio levels just right.

What I'm doing right now, is first "normalizing" the audio from the individual singers like this:

- Extract audio into a WAV file using ffmpeg
- Load the WAV file into my application using NAudio
- Find the maximum 16-bit value
- When I create the merged video, specify a volume for this stream that boosts the maximum value to 32767

So, for example, if I have 3 streams: stream A's maximum audio is 32767 already, stream B's maximum audio is 32000, and stream C's maximum audio is 16000, then when I merge these videos I will specify

```
[0:a]volume=1.0,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud0]
[1:a]volume=1.02,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud1]
[2:a]volume=2.05,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud2]
[aud0][aud1][aud2]amix=inputs=3[a]
```

(I have an additional "volume tweak" that lets me adjust the volume level of individual singers as necessary, but we can ignore that for this question)

I am reading the ffmpeg wiki on [Audio Volume Manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume), and I will implement that next, but I don't know what to do with the output it generates.  It looks like I'm going to get mean and max volume levels in dB and while I understand decibels in a "yeah, I learned about those in college 30 years ago" kind of way, I don't know how to use those values to normalize the audio of my input videos.

The problem is, in the ffmpeg output video, the audio level is quite low.  If I do the same process of extracting the audio and looking at the WAV file in the merged video that ffmpeg generated, the maximum value is only 4904.

How do I implement an algorithm that automatically sets the output volume to a "reasonable" level?  I realize I can simply add a manual volume filter and have the human set the level, but that's going to be a lot of back & forth of generating the merged video, listening to it, adjusting the level, merging again, etc.  I want a way where my application figures out an appropriate output volume (possibly with human adjustment allowed).

EDIT

Asking ffmpeg to determine the mean and max volume of each clip does provide mean and max volume in dB, and I can then use those values to scale each input clip:

```
[0:a]volume=3.40dB,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud0]
[1:a]volume=3.90dB,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud1]
[2:a]volume=4.40dB,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud2]
[3:a]volume=-0.00dB,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud3]
```

But my final video is still strangely quiet.  For now, I've added a manually-entered volume factor that gets applied at the very end:

```
[aud0][aud1][aud2]amix=inputs=3[a]
[a]volume=volume=3.00[b]
```

So my question is, in effect, how do I determine algorithmically what this final volume factor needs to be?

MORE EDIT

There's something deeper going on here, I just set the volume filter to 100 and the output is only slightly louder.  Here are my filters, and the relevant portions of the command line:

```
color=size=1920x1080:c=0x0000FF [base];
[0:v] scale=576x324 [clip0];
[0:a]volume=1.48,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud0];
[1:v] crop=808:1022:202:276,scale=384x486 [clip1];
[1:a]volume=1.57,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud1];
[2:v] crop=1160:1010:428:70,scale=558x486 [clip2];
[2:a]volume=1.66,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud2];
[3:v] crop=1326:1080:180:0,scale=576x469 [clip3];
[3:a]volume=1.70,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud3];
[4:a]volume=0.20,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud4];
[5:a]volume=0.73,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud5];
[6:v] crop=1326:1080:276:0,scale=576x469 [clip4];
[6:a]volume=1.51,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud6];
[base][clip0] overlay=shortest=1:x=32:y=158 [tmp0];
[tmp0][clip1] overlay=shortest=1:x=768:y=27 [tmp1];
[tmp1][clip2] overlay=shortest=1:x=1321:y=27 [tmp2];
[tmp2][clip3] overlay=shortest=1:x=32:y=625 [tmp3];
[tmp3][clip4] overlay=shortest=1:x=672:y=625 [tmp4];
[aud0][aud1][aud2][aud3][aud4][aud5][aud6]amix=inputs=7[a];
[a]adelay=delays=200:all=1[b];
[b]volume=volume=100.00[c];
[c]asplit[a1][a2];

ffmpeg -y ....
   -map "[tmp4]" -map "[a1]" -c:v libx264 "D:\voutput.mp4" 
   -map "[a2]" "D:\aoutput.mp3""
```

When I do this, the audio I want is louder (loud enough to clip and get distorted), but definitely not 100x louder.

Comment: See my answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/35509147/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62367391/

Comment: Using the dynaudnorm filter worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. after mixing audio, run

`ffmpeg -i output.mp3 -filter:a volumedetect -map 0:a -f null /dev/null`

2. get value from string like this:

`[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0xdigitsletters] max_volume: -16.5 dB`

3. add to filters this value, but positive: `...]amix=inputs=7,volume=16.5dB[a]`

[edit]

do it after mixing audio.

[update]

I did some investigation:

[update 2]

```
#!/bin/bash
f="input 1.mp3"
INP=("-ss" "30" "-i" "$f")
FCT=1
FLA="[0:a:0]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[0a0]; "
AUD="[0a0]"
MAX=$(ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$f" -map 0:a -filter:a volumedetect -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | grep 'max_volume' | awk '{print $4, $5, $6}')
echo "    $FCT $MAX"
for f in /mnt/sklad/Музыка/*.mp3; do
  INP+=("-ss" "30" "-i" "$f")
  FLA+="[${FCT}:a:0]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[${FCT}a0]; "
  AUD+="[${FCT}a0]"
  ((FCT++))
  printf -v OUT "%02d" $FCT
  ffmpeg -v error -hide_banner "${INP[@]}" -filter_complex "${FLA} ${AUD}amix=inputs=${FCT}[a]" -map [a] -c:a aac -q:a 4 -t 30 -y "out_${OUT}.mkv"
  MAX=$(ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$f" -map 0:a -filter:a volumedetect -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | grep 'max_volume' | awk '{print $5, $6}')
  echo "    $FCT $MAX"
done

for f in out_*.mkv; do
  MAX=$(ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$f" -map 0:a -filter:a volumedetect -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | grep 'max_volume' | awk '{print $5, $6}')
  echo "    $f $MAX"
done
```

output:

```
1 max_volume: -1.1 dB
2 -0.2 dB
3 0.0 dB
4 -1.9 dB
5 -0.1 dB
6 -0.9 dB
7 0.0 dB
8 0.0 dB
9 0.0 dB
10 0.0 dB
11 0.0 dB
12 0.0 dB
13 -0.5 dB
14 -1.1 dB
15 0.0 dB
16 0.0 dB
17 -0.0 dB
out_02.mkv -4.4 dB
out_03.mkv -5.0 dB
out_04.mkv -6.8 dB
out_05.mkv -7.1 dB
out_06.mkv -8.3 dB
out_07.mkv -8.9 dB
out_08.mkv -8.9 dB
out_09.mkv -8.8 dB
out_10.mkv -8.9 dB
out_11.mkv -9.7 dB
out_12.mkv -10.3 dB
out_13.mkv -11.1 dB
out_14.mkv -11.3 dB
out_15.mkv -10.6 dB
out_16.mkv -10.9 dB
out_17.mkv -11.2 dB
```

get other result, but still there is no strong pattern

Comment: I'll give it a try, but won't this do pretty much exactly the same thing I was doing already, just specifying the volume in dB instead of a multiplicative factor?

Comment: So this doesn't answer my question at all?  My final, merged, video will still have a very low volume?